# ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment at Object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to finish an OAuth2 flow, but keep getting an uncaught referenceerror. Fairly new to Node.js and cant seem to find out what's going on.

```
// require the blockspring package.
var blockspring = require('blockspring');
var request = require('request');

// pass your function into blockspring.define. tells blockspring what function to run.
blockspring.define(function(request, response) {

    // retrieve input parameters and assign to variables for convenience.
    var buffer_clientid = request.params["buffer_clientid"];
    var buffer_secret = request.params["buffer_secret"];
    var redirectURI = request.params["redirectURI"];
    var tokencode = request.params["tokencode"];


    request({
      method: "POST",
      url: "https://api.bufferapp.com/1/oauth2/token.json",
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'request',
      }, 
      body: client_id=buffer_clientid&client_secret=buffer_secret&redirect_uri=redirectURI&code=tokencode&grant_type=authorization_code

    }, function(error, response, body){
      console.log(body);

      // return the output.
      response.end();
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to put quotes around your `body` data. `client_id=buffer...` should be a string. You're trying to assign something to `client_id` which doesn't exist.

Comment: The body key in request object needs to be formatted as a string. You either need to concat using `'string' + variable + 'string'`

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid JavaScript syntax:

```
   body: client_id=buffer_clientid&client_secret=buffer_secret&redirect_uri=redirectURI&code=tokencode&grant_type=authorization_code
```

I'm assuming you are trying to concatenate your variable values to a string? Try this instead:

```
   body: "client_id=" + buffer_clientid + "&client_secret=" + buffer_secret + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectURI + "&code=" + tokencode + "&grant_type=" +authorization_code
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings in nodejs need to be quoted. In your request function, you're passing a key of body, with a value of what appears to be a giant variable. Because there are no quotes around `client_id=buffer_clientid&client_secret=buffer_secret&redirect_uri=redirectURI&code=tokencode&grant_type=authorization_code`, it's trying to treat this as a variable. When the parser gets to the `=` sign, it's trying to then set client_id = the following. This is throwing the error.

Simply quote the entire string or if you need to use variables concat using `'string' + variable + 'string'`.

Judging by your variable names, you can simple rewrite it as follows:

```
request({
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://api.bufferapp.com/1/oauth2/token.json",
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'request',
  }, 
  body: 'client_id=' + buffer_clientid + '&client_secret=' + buffer_secret + '&redirect_uri=' + redirectURI + '&code=' + tokencode + '&grant_type=authorization_code'

}, function(error, response, body){
  console.log(body);

  // return the output.
  response.end();
})
```